# Word order with pronouns and adverbs in Spanish

Tags: gramática, pronombres, adverbios, orden-de-palabras

Can someone explain the word order in the sentence below and help me understand the grammar?

> Mi mamá siempre me compra muñecas. <sub>My mom always buys me dolls.</sub>

Although incorrect, I keep wanting to parse it as:

> Mi mamá me siempre compra muñecas

because I'm confused about word order with Spanish pronouns and adverbs.

Comment: Note that your sentence only had one adjective: *mi*. I'm guessing you mean adverbs

Comment: You could also say "Mi mamá me compra muñecas siempre" or "Mi mamá me compra siempre muñecas" but either way _me_ goes always before of the verb "compra". You can move the time adverb "siempre" up and down but not between "me" and "compra"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In modern Spanish, unstressed pronouns (that is,  *me, te, se, le, lo, la, nos, os, les, los, las*) must always come either directly before (with a space) or directly after (without a space) a verb.

By placing *me* in front of *siempre*, we violate that rule.

Note that I did say modern Spanish. It is possible to find examples of exactly the order you describe in the first part of the 1500s and before:

> La razón que me siempre dexistes (Amadís de Gaula, 1482).
>
> entended señor en me siempre ayudar (trad. de Crónica de Aragón, 1499).
>
> e ell ángel que me siempre guardó de todo mal bendiga estos niños (Alfonso X, c. 1275)